# Is Ghost in Azure leaking email passwords or is Gmail warning for nothing?

Tags: security, azure, passwords, gmail, ghost-blog

Yesterday I created a new Ghost Blog website from the Azure website gallery. The installation there asks for Gmail account and passwords, and like any security fanatic I gave my personal gmail account information (mistake #1).

Everything went nicely and got the blog up and running in no time.

Moment went and I got an email from Gmail saying that there has been suspicious log in to my gmail account from Taiwan. Google blocked this login and I made quick password change.

Today I repeated everything, but created new account to gmail to test things out. Same thing happened, but this time the login was from unknown location.

I scanned my computer for keyloggers and didn't find any.

Is it just Google being cautious and warning that the Ghost is trying to send mail and performing login while doing it? Or are those passwords leaking? They are in clear text format in the ghost configs?

**Edit:**
Screen capture of the Ghost Setup in Azure
[image]

To my knowledge this seems totally normal Azure configure step.

Comment: To edit: Azure is relevant if default setup makes the config visible, I will put the azure tag back, but will remove if someone tells that it is impossible to be azure's problem. Also Azure wizard is the one asking these informations.

Comment: I did install Ghost from Azure gallery and there was no questions about my gmail accounts. Something must be phishy with your PC.

Comment: I added an screenshot from azure. To me it looks very normal step of azure "Add new Website" wizard. It of course isn't impossible to steal passwords like this, but if attack software has power to modify my received web pages in web browser, it would get the passwords much more easier :)

Comment: Azure does ask for your Gmail/MailGun/SendGrid credentials to pre-populate the config.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password is stored in clear text in the `config.js` file, but that is just fine because the file is not accessible from the web.

The reason why GMail complains might be that, in order to send mail, Ghost has to log in to your account with your password. In this case, requests are not coming from your personal computer, but from the Azure server that is in a data center [somewhere](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/).

But it's probably not the best idea to ignore the warning, because somebody might have actually breached your account. I would simply use another service for Ghost (like [Mailgun](http://docs.ghost.org/mail/#mailgun)).

Comment: To my opinion clear text is always security risk, it only needs single mistake in the code that makes this file or setting visible to the attacker (file path injection etc.). In the matter of the actual answer, it is probably the case that Google is over cautious and ghost from azure server is accessing the account. I tried searching that does Azure have some server in Taiwan, but didn't find any.

Comment: OK, I actually traced the IP address that Google said the access happened. It seems that it is actually Microsoft's data center in Ireland, not from Taiwan like Google suggested. So it is just Google being over cautious. I also jumped using mailgun, because GMail is probably not the right way to do it.